F# - unwanted reference to FSharp.Core 9.0 after paket clear-cache causes build error
I recently ran a somewhat bold paket clear-cache and my F# application started behaving strangely. Some of my projects that were referencing an older version of FSharp.Core now reference the new v9.0.
I never paid attention to it, maybe a similar move was also bumping versions before but it has always transparent for me. Now I wouldn't mind if I didn't get this dreaded error at compile time this time: File '.../.nuget/packages/fsharp.core/9.0.100/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Core.optdata' not found alongside FSharp.Core.
What I tried so far:

Deleting FSharp.Core v9.0 from my global NuGet folder doesn't work - same missing file error message.
Replacing the paket-downloaded 9.0 nuget package with one directly from the source at nuget.org. Still the missing file error.
Checked paket.lock and paket why. FSharp.Core >=9.0 is not present in any dependency chain.
Set FSharp.Core explicitly to an older version in paket.dependencies and ran paket install and restore. Still no luck, my project keeps refering to 9.0. <-- This is the most surprising to me, as I always thought Paket tried to enforce the versions or failed.
Set DependencyVersion to Lowest in my NuGet.config file.
Referenced an older version of FSharp.Core explicitly in my fsproj files. It compiles, but when I run one of the (Fable-based) projects I get no successful import of /.../.nuget/packages/fsharp.core/9.0.100/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Core.dllstartup - probably because Fable does a dotnet restore that reinstates 9.0 as a dependency.

Note: all builds attempts were both in my IDE (Rider) and with dotnet build.
My best bet now is that a non-Paket managed library has a dependency to FSharp.Core and DependencyVersion Lowest somehow didn't work, resulting in the newly released version of FSharp.Core being used, but I didn't add references lately and I try to keep all my stuff in Paket, so any help is welcome.

OK, I solved it by cleaning all bin and obj directories in the projects and referencing a strict version of FSharp.Core in paket.dependencies. Still weird that FSharp.Core 9 was referenced in the first place...
